# Accounting for Recurring Combinations When Calculating Average Expected Value With Variable Number of Levels

Tags: probability, statistics

A single player plays a game (for example, against a casino). They bet `$1` and toss a coin. If they don't guess, the game is over (no more tosses are allowed). If they guess, the casino pays them `$2` and they may either **withdraw the prize** (in this case, the game is over) or **toss the coin one more time**. The game can represented in the form of a binary tree (for simplicity, let's suppose no more than `3` games (levels) are allowed).

[image: game tree]

There are the following possible loss and win combinations:
`T`, `HT`, `HHT`: `-$1`.
`H`: `$2`.
`HH`: `$4`.
`HHH`: `$8`.

I think the logic is the following: to win an `X` prize, the player have to play `N` games on average:
`$2` … `2 games`: `1` win game (`H`), `1` loss game (`T`).
`$4` … `4 games`: `1` win game (`HH`), `3` loss games (`2 × T`, `HT`).
`$8` … `8 games`: `1` win game (`HHH`), `7` loss games (`4 × T`, `2 × HT`, `HHT`).

As it can be seen, the list of loss combinations for the **larger** prize contains the loss combinations for the **smaller** prizes.

If to take into account all the combinations, the average prize, I think, will be the following:
$$ win_{avg}=\frac{(1\times\$2-1\times\$1) + (1\times\$4-3\times\$1) + (1\times\$8-7\times\$1)}{2+4+8} \approx \$0.21 $$

If to exclude all the recurring combinations, the average prize, I suppose, will be the following:
$$ win_{avg}=\frac{1\times\$2+1\times\$4+1\times\$8-7\times\$1}{1+1+1+7} = \$0.70 $$

When calculating an expected average payout for a single game, how to account for recurring combinations? Which variant is correct (if any)?

Comment: Hi, ENIAC, it looks a little bit vague, for example, how many players participate this game, who gives the money, etc? Can you elaborate the rules of the game?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Mountain! Thank you for letting me know! I've added some info. There is only 1 player playing against casino. In short, the rules for each coin toss are the following: (1) if the player doesn't guess, they lose and game stops; (2) if the plater guesses, their bet or winnings are doubled and they may either (2a) withdraw the winnings (and the game stops) or (2b) play the next level (all levels are the same, coin toss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to compute an expected payout, since one important piece of information is missing, namely, in those situations where the player has a choice of actions, we don't know the probability that the player will toss the coin again. E.g., we can't compute the probability of winning two dollars, since we don't know, after tossing heads on the first try, whether the player will toss again, or quit.

So, let's assume that when the player has a choice, then half the time the player quits, and half the time the player plays on. Now we can do a computation:

Outcome: T. Probability: $1/2$. Payoff: $-1$.
Outcome: H. Probability: $1/4$. Payoff: $2$.
Outcome: HT. Probability: $1/8$. Payoff: $-1$.
Outcome: HH. Probability: $1/16$. Payoff: $4$.
Outcome: HHT. Probability: $1/32$. Payoff: $-1$.
Outcome: HHH. Probability: $1/32$. Payoff: $8$.

Expected payoff: $(1/2)(-1)+(1/4)2+(1/8)(-1)+(1/16)4+(1/32)(-1)+(1/32)8=11/32$.

Comment: Gerry, thank you for your detailed and clear answer! Your idea of dividing the probability of winning and continuing the game that way is very interesting. BTW, I assumed withdrawal and continuing have the same probability too. And your solution is very close to mine ($ 7/32 \approx 0.21 $). But your method of calculation is simpler than mine.

Comment: Sorry, $7/32$ was an arithmetical error I made. I have corrected it to $11/32$.