# Accounting for Bet in Bonus Game of Slot Game

Tags: probability

###### Question

Should the `bet` be separated from the `payout` when analysing a `bonus` game of a slot game (like it is done when analysing a `base` game)?

---

###### Description

When calculating the RTP (return to player) of a slot game, the `bet` and `payout` are considered separately. For example, let's say there are `20` combinations are possible, of which only `8` combinations pay (let's suppose `2x`). The RTP of the base game is:

$$bet=\$1$$

$$RTP_{base\ game}=\frac{payout}{total\ bet}=\frac{8\times(2\times$1)}{20\times\$1}=\frac{\$16}{\$20}=80\%$$

**Note that** the `payout` **doesn't** account for the `bet` a player pays **before** clicking the button. Thus, their **real** win for `2x` (for a single combination) will be `$1`, not `$2` (`–bet + payout = –$1 + 2 × $1`).

---

Let's suppose when the player gets a winning combination, they are proposed to play the `bonus` game: coin toss. The player may take the `winnings` or play the bonus game. If they win the `bonus` game, their `payout` gets doubled. If they lose, they just lose their `bet` (that they deposited before playing the `base` game), the bonus game ends. To calculate the average winnings for a single game, the following distribution of the `bonus` games will be used:

$$n_{games\ total}=16\ games$$

| # | $prize$ | $\boldsymbol{n_{win\ \&\ continue}}$ | $\boldsymbol{n_{win\ \&\ take}}$ | $\boldsymbol{n_{lose}}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | $8\times bet=\$8$ | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | $4\times bet=\$4$ | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 0 | $2\times bet=\$2$ | 8 | 8 | 0 |

But since the `bet` is not included into the `payout` for the `base` game analysis, should the same be done for the `bonus` game analysis? Below, there are the `3` variants that I considered but I cannot figure out which is appropriate (if any).

---

$$ Total\ payout=\sum_{i=0}^2 (n_{win\ \&\ take\ i}\times prize_i - n_{lose\ i}\times bet)=$$

$$=8\times\$2-0\times\$1+2\times\$4-4\times\$1+1\times\$8-1\times\$1=\$27 $$

$$ Average\ payout=\$27 / 16 = \$1.6875 $$

(looks like the player **doesn't** deposit their `bet` before clicking the button)

---

$$ Total\ payout=\sum_{i=0}^2 (n_{win\ \&\ take\ i}\times prize_i)=$$

$$=8\times\$2+2\times\$4+1\times\$8=\$32 $$

$$ Average\ payout=\$32 / 16 = \$2 $$

(equals to the `base` game `payout` which is `2x`)

---

$$ Total\ payout=\sum_{i=0}^2 (n_{win\ \&\ take\ i}\times{prize_i})-n_{games\ total}\times{bet}=$$

$$=(8\times\$2+2\times\$4+1\times\$8)-16\times\$1=\$16 $$

$$ Average\ payout=\$16 / 16 = \$1 $$

(pure win of the player)

---

Which $RTP_{total}$ is correct?

$$RTP_{total}=\frac{8\times\$1.6875}{20\times\$1}=\frac{\$13.5}{\$20}=67.5\%$$

$$RTP_{total}=\frac{8\times\$2}{20\times\$1}=\frac{\$16}{\$20}=80\%$$

$$RTP_{total}=\frac{8\times\$1}{20\times\$1}=\frac{\$8}{\$20}=40\%$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer: since the bet is not accounted in the base game, it should be disregarded when calculating an `RTP` for the bonus game too, since the total bet goes to the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The return to player is just what the player receives at the end of the game divided by the bet the player makes.  What mechanics go on inside the game do not matter.  There may be exit points along the way and you need to define the player's strategy at those points.  You should not add together the winnings from win and continue and win and take as the player only gets one of those.  I don't understand your bonus structure at all.  In the original game the RTP was $80\%$ as you say.  If the player plays each of those wins again s/he will win $\frac 16\%$ of the time and get $4$ in those cases.  The RTP is then $64\%$

Comment: Ross, thank you for your answer! The logic of the bonus game is exactly the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715040/accounting-for-recurring-combinations-when-calculating-average-expected-value-wi). In short, the player has 3 choices (play, stop, and continue).

Comment: Also, I didn't add `win & continue` and `win & take`.